# Im having trouble connecting Azure Active Directory to Wiki.js

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, wiki.js

I have followed this guide exactly multiple times without issue.

https://docs.requarks.io/auth/azure

But when I try to log in with Azure Active Directory, I get a white page with "Not Found".

Can anyone help troubleshoot this, i'm not sure what else I can do and I need to get this up and running.

Comment: Can you try with the redirect URI of app registration as https://YOUR-WIKI.DOMAIN.COM/.auth/login/aad/callback

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today. You need to scroll down to the bottom of the Wiki.js settings page and use the redirect url there rather than the one suggested on the help pages.